# Newrelic won't show info about php CLI script

Tags: php, newrelic

In my config `/etc/newrelic/nrsysmond.cfg` I have:

```
license_key=myKeyHash
loglevel=info
logfile=/var/log/newrelic/nrsysmond.log
```

In my php CLI script I have:

```
newrelic_background_job(true);
newrelic_set_appname('test');
newrelic_name_transaction('cliTest');
```

But on newrelic admin web page I see nothing.

Is it possible to see info about shell scripts in newrelic?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that script is worker which continuously works in loop, and for such situations I need explicitly call:

```
newrelic_end_transaction();
```

PS: Thanks Carlos Castro for help!